# Why might this cause the file to be empty?

Tags: bash, unix

```
TMP="$$.FILE"

#Process puts contents into TMP

cat "$TMP" | sort |  head > "$TMP"
```

I already made sure the file was not empty to begin with. Without the `> "$TMP"`, it outputs something, but when its stored again into the same file, its empty. What might be the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those processes all get run in parallel, so the head command is truncating the file before cat has a chance to read it.

To get the result you want, you need to write the sort output to a different file then move that over the original.

```
cat "$TMP" | sort | head > "$TMP".new
mv "$TMP".new "$TMP"
```

Comment: `sort "$TMP" | head > "$TMP".new && mv "$TMP".new "$TMP"` will keep from clobbering the file if there's an error (and it gives `cat` a rest).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot write to and read from a file at the same time. Here is roughly what happens:

1. `> "$TMP"` causes file to be opened for writing, which also truncates the file.
2. `cat "$TMP"` reads from now blank file.
3. File stays empty.

Commands that purport to modify a file in place in fact perform a bit of temp file shuffling under the covers. For example, `sed -i` will process an input file and save the results to `input.tmp`, then do `mv input.tmp input` at the end to overwrite the original. You should follow that model.

Comment: I see, so what is a solution around it? Create another TMP file?

Answer (score 1):

The last pipe will truncate the file which the first pipe reads, before anything really happens. So what happens is `cat` tries to read a file which the call to `head` immediately truncated. This is the causing the issues here; the `>` operator is a shell operator which means "truncate this file right away and then have the process write its standard output into the file.

On a related note, you don't need `cat` here.

Try this instead:

```
TMP="$$.FILE"    
sort <"$TMP" | head > "$TMP.tmp"
mv "$TMP.tmp" "$TMP"
```